# Jenkins workflow (pipeline) + JobDSL plugin - SCM does not work

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to integrate pipelineJob dsl into jenkins DSL(by jenkins DSL plugin).

As seen the API reference in jenkins DSL, there is argument for my purpose.
pipelineJob -> scm -> git

But after generation, there is no scm view at all in the UI and I found that if I made the pure pipelineJob, there was also no UI for scm.

I tracked the pipeline plugin source and realized that pipelineJob inherited job, so I thought there should be SCM-related option like normal job.

Is there any way to achieve get the normal scm UI in pipeline job? or Do I have to achieve my purpose by groovy script only?

Jenkins job DSL below

```
def projects = [
    'Nova',
    'Keystone',
    'Cinder',
    'Glance',
    'Horizon',
    'Neutron',
    'Networking-kakao',
    'Neutron-fwaas',
    'Neutron-lbaas',
    'Octavia',
    'Ceilometer',
    'Heat',
    'Sahara',
    'Trove'
]

def codeName = 'mitaka'
def ref = 'kakao/' + codeName

projects.each {
  def project = it
  def jobName = 'Unit/OpenStack/' + project

  project = project.toLowerCase()
  pipelineJob(jobName) {
    logRotator(daysToKeep = 7, numToKeep = 5)

    scm {
        concurrentBuild()
        git {
            remote {
           url("https://github.com/openstack/${project}.git")

            }
            branch("${ref}")
            extensions {
                wipeOutWorkspace()
            }
        }
    }

    definition {
        cps {
            sandbox()
            script("""
            node {
            stage ('Clone Sources') {
            git {
            remote {
            url("https://github.com/openstack/${project}.git")
            credentials("ccc")
            }
            branch("${ref}")
            extensions {
            wipeOutWorkspace()
            }
            }
            git {
            url 'https://github.com/openstack-tox-base.git'
            branch 'rewrite'
            }
            sh 'cp tox-openstack-base/Dockerfile.test Dockerfile'
            }

            docker.withServer('tcp://...:2375') {
              def img
              def base = docker.image('idock.daumkakao.io/openstack/tox/test-base:newton2')

              stage ('Build Test Image') {
                base.pull()
                  img = docker.build("tox/newton/test-horizon")
              }

            stage ('Run Test') {
              sh "docker run --rm tox/newton/test-horizon"
            }
            }
            }

      """.stripIndent())
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Pipelines are configured via code and that's good. You can configure the SCM in your JobDSL code using `scm`. Have a look at the [API viewer](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/pipelineJob-scm). And you have the same means in pipeline. I suggest that you get familiar with [Jenkins Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/).

Comment: @StephenKing Yes, that's why I post this question. From the API reference, I supposed to use that scm in JobDSL. But it does not generated SCM at all. (Also pipeline job does not have any scm view)

Comment: PLS post your code , so I can try and help

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: I posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

The Pipeline job does not support the `scm` block. Unfortunately, the Job DSL API allows to use the `scm` block in `pipelineJob`. That is an open issue in Job DSL, see [JENKINS-31832](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31832).

To load your Pipeline script from SCM, use the `cpsScm` block:

```
pipelineJob('example') {
  definition {
    cpsScm {
      scm {
        git('https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git')
      }
    }
  }
}
```